# Swift CMutablePointers in factories e.g. NewMusicSequence

Tags: swift

How do you use C level factory methods in Swift?

Let's try using a factory such as NewMusicSequence().

```
var status:OSStatus
var sequence:MusicSequence
status=NewMusicSequence(&sequence)
```

This errors out with "error: variable 'sequence' passed by reference before being initialized".
Set sequence to nil, and you get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

You can try being explicit like this:

```
var sp:CMutablePointer<MusicSequence>=nil
status=NewMusicSequence(sp)
```

But then you get a bad access exception when you set sp to nil. If you don't set sp, you get an "error: variable 'sp' used before being initialized"

I'd expect this to be the way to do it, but it's not:

```
import AudioToolbox
var sequence: MusicSequence?
var status:OSStatus = NewMusicSequence(&sequence)
```

error: cannot convert the expression's type 'OSStatus' to type 'inout MusicSequence?'
var status:OSStatus = NewMusicSequence(&sequence)

Here's the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NewMusicSequence).

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you need an optional value. Optional values are always initialized to `nil` and only optional values can ever be `nil`.

```
var sequence: MusicSequence?
let status = NewMusicSequence(&sequence)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried that also. This yields:error: cannot convert the expression's type 'OSStatus' to type 'inout MusicSequence?'
let status = NewMusicSequence(&sequence)

Comment: What about `var sequence = CMutablePointer<MusicSequence>?` and then `let status = NewMusicSequence(&sequence)` I made a typo, the function takes a `CMutablePointer<MusicSequence>` according to the documentation.

Comment: I'm thinking this is a bug. A `CMutablePointer<Type>` argument should allow a `Type` or `Type[]` argument to be passed without issue. See `dispatch_once` for example. The problem is that `MusicSequence` seems to be type aliased to `COpaquePointer`, which is a `void *`. I assume this is initialized to `NULL` but using `COpaquePointer.null()` still crashes... weird.

Comment: @kmikael, re using CMutablePointer. The interop doc says just using the & operator you get a CMutablePointer. Here's the output. error: cannot convert the expression's type 'OSStatus' to type 'inout CMutablePointer<MusicSequence>?'
let s = NewMusicSequence(&sequence)
                         ^~~~~~~~~
for this code: var sequence: CMutablePointer<MusicSequence>?
let s = NewMusicSequence(&sequence)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in an Xcode project. It seems to throw **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** in the playground for some reason.

```
import Foundation
import AudioToolbox

@objc class SwiftSequenceGenerator : NSObject
{
    @objc func createMusicSequence() -> MusicSequence
    {
        var status : OSStatus = 0
        var sequence : MusicSequence = MusicSequence()

        status = NewMusicSequence(&sequence)

        return sequence
    }
}

let generator = SwiftSequenceGenerator()
let sequence = generator.createMusicSequence()
```

I was testing this in an Obj-C project, hence the `@objc` attributes. Both this and its Obj-C counterpart were able to generate a new `MusicSequence`.

It is a little tricky because `MusicSequence` is actually a `struct`. In Obj-C it is defined as a pointer `OpaqueMusicSequence` and Swift uses `COpaquePointer`. They are basically the same, using a `void *` to pass the `MusicSequence` struct to the factory method to be mutated.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I've used these classes (MusicSequence etc) in OC for years - and I wanted to try them in Swift. Yes, I'm using the playground, so that seems to be the problem. Just this: var sequence : MusicSequence = MusicSequence() yields EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. So, I'm wondering if playground will be useful here. It would be nice for real time tinkering with sequences etc sort of like you can with Overtone/Clojure via Emacs.